# Уникальные комментарии для каждой новости через php

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

Не могу додуматься, как реализовать данную задачу именно в прописи кода. У меня есть в БД табличка  новостей и табличка комментариев, но я не знаю как их связать, кому не лень, расскажите хоть примерно, как решит эту банальную задачу, заранее спасибо!

Comment: `mysql join` - гуглите

Answer (score 2):

Добавляйте к каждому комментарию ID новости, к которому был добавлен комментарий. Далее сможете извлечь все комментарии через where ID

Comment: а как добавить добавить ID новости к комментарию?

Answer (score 0):

Сязываются таблицы между собой уникальным ключом, что часто называют ID. Например у одной статьи (в вашем случаи новость) могут быть несколько комментариев и у всех этих комментариев ID одной статьи. Можете почитать [тут](http://jtest.ru/bazyi-dannyix/sql-dlya-nachinayushhix-chast-3.html)